# Invoke-sqlcmd to remote server issue: Could not find file

Tags: sql-server, powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script which will execute tsql query to only one remote server using invoke-sqlcmd. Those tsql queries are simple one like backup/restore database, create a user, etc.
Below is an extract of it :

```
  # 5 # Create clientdb database on secondary server by restoring the full backup for primary
  Try {
      Invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'REMOTESQLSRV'`
        -Username 'ts_sql' -Password 'somepassword'`
        -InputFile "$LScltid\__01_On_Secondary_CreateDB2_srv2.sql"`
        -ErrorAction Stop

      Write-Host " clt_$id is now restored to secondary server "`
        -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor Green
} Catch {
    Write-Host " Restore operation for clt_$id did not succeed. Check the error logs " -ForegroundColor Black -BackgroundColor Red 
}
```

My scripts always break here. For some reasons that i could not put my head on, invoke-sqlcmd does not use the variable "$LScltid" to resolve the path where it will find the .sql script.

Everytime i had to run it, it change the current directory to either the SQLERVER:\ provider or some other causing the script to failed at this step.

Am I doing this the right way? If so, how should i adapt the command to perform as I expect it to.?

**UPDATE**
Forgot to mention, if i run the script with the variables values hard-coded I'm able to get the result i need (in this case restoring a database from device).

Thanks for your feedbacks.

Comment: The standard debugging way is to use `write-host` to print the command on console. Then copy-paste the results back onto Powershell prompt and see if the command has valid syntax. Use copy-paste in order to use the command as-is. If you type, you might fix errors on spacing, punctuation and whatnot.

Comment: Hello vonPryz. thanks for the debugging suggestion. I always use Windows Powershell ISE to write/debug/correct the script i interact with. This, i think, help narrow down the amount of error one could have.

Answer (score 0):

Odd thing, the command is now working. I don't really know what i've done wrong previously, but the exact same command is now working.
Just a heads up for those facing the same issue:

If you have to use `Invoke-Sqlcmd` in your scripts, beware of the provider change especially if the commands coming after `Invoque-Sqlcmd` are regulars one (get, set, copy, new, etc....) 
In my case, somewhere in my script between two `Invoke-sqlcmd` commands i had to copy files from local to remote server. Everytime the command failed because the provider changed. As a workaround I `set-location` before `copy-item` command execution and that maneuver seemed to do the trick (don't know if its re-commanded tough.

Thanks **Stackoverflow Team**